# Java 8 bad performance , sorting

Tags: java

I solve algorithmic problems on codeforces and I tried pushing the same solution using java 7 and java 8 and to my surprise using java 8 I got much worse solution.

On the last test:
Java 7:
time: 373 ms., memory: 112 KB

java 8:
time: 623 ms., memory: 3664 KB

My code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = in.nextInt();
    int m = in.nextInt();
    List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>(n);
    List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>(m);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        list1.add(in.nextInt());
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        list2.add(in.nextInt());
    }

    Collections.sort(list1);
    Collections.sort(list2, Collections.reverseOrder());

    int max = Math.min(list1.size(), list2.size());
    int a,b;
    long result = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<max;i++) {
        a = list1.get(i);
        b = list2.get(i);
        if(b > a) result += ( b- a);
        else break;
    }

    System.out.println(result);


}
```

Why is that ?

Comment: Suspect startup overhead or possibly autoboxing shenanigans. Run the clock in `main` alone to eliminate the first possibility.

Comment: Are you consistently getting these results?

Comment: I run it one more time and results are similar

Comment: I _suspect_ the garbage collection.

Comment: @Bathsheba, I don't have java 8 on my computer, but I'll check this possibility later, thank you

Comment: Your IO is highly likely affecting your timings.  You need to test this repeatedly e.g. for 10 seconds, without including the time to load the data.  Also you should test the two lists separately. It could be that one is slower and the other is not.  Also if you are concerned about speed, I suggest using an `int[]` rather than an ArrayList.  If you don't care about speed, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: PeterLawrey I used int[] , but I got time limit exceed so I changed it to arrayList and it works fine. @Bathsheba, I installed java 8 on my computer and I tried measuring time with System.currentTimeMillis() and there are results: Java 7 ( 114ms, 65 ms, 68 ms, 61 ms, 85 ms... ) and java 8( 29 ms, 31 ms, 32 ms, 45 ms .. ) so you are right, time was worse due to startup overhead or IO operations ( because now I randomize elements), but what about memory ?. Please write answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many points not clear about the question. These are obvious things, like how you are running the timing test, how you are providing the input numbers, and what the size of the input numbers is.

Also, when you say that storing 2*100000 `Integer` objects in Java 7 should only need 112KB, then there must be some magic compression involved, because the data itself will already take at least 800 KB, ignoring any further object overhead. Additionally, the sorting should not even take 373ms with the numbers that you mentioned, but maybe only 50ms on a modern PC.

However, there have been some hints in the comments that I'll try to assemble here, hoping that it will be considered helpful (and maybe even answer your question).

---

First of all, microbenchmarking is an art, and there are many things to consider. In order to obtain "reliable" results, you have to use a microbenchmarking toolkit like [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) or [Caliper](https://code.google.com/p/caliper/). But to quickly get a rough approximation of the results, you should at least repeat the actual test several times. For your case, this could *roughly* be done like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class SortingSpeedTest {

    private static List<Integer> createList(int n, int offset, int range) {
        Random random = new Random(0);
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(n);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            list.add(random.nextInt(range) + offset);
        }
        return list;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int m = 1000; m <= 1000000; m *= 10) {
            for (int n = 1000; n <= 1000000; n *= 10) {

                runTest(m, n);
            }
        }

    }

    private static void runTest(int m, int n) {
        List<Integer> list1 = createList(m, 0, 100);
        List<Integer> list2 = createList(n, 100, 100);

        long before = System.nanoTime();
        Collections.sort(list1);
        Collections.sort(list2, Collections.reverseOrder());
        int max = Math.min(list1.size(), list2.size());
        int a, b;
        long result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
            a = list1.get(i);
            b = list2.get(i);
            if (b > a)
                result += (b - a);
            else
                break;
        }
        long after = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.printf("m=%7d n=%7d result=%14d duration %8.3f\n", m, n,
                result, (after - before) / 1e6);
    }
}
```

On my machine (omitting some details here, because the reliability is not sooo high anyhow), when started with `-Xmx1500m -server`, this gives the following results with Java 7

```
m=   1000 n=   1000 result=        100000 duration    5,985
m=   1000 n=  10000 result=        144379 duration   26,641
m=   1000 n= 100000 result=        149303 duration   38,308
m=   1000 n=1000000 result=        149336 duration  148,365
m=  10000 n=   1000 result=        145269 duration    9,068
m=  10000 n=  10000 result=       1000000 duration   11,799
m=  10000 n= 100000 result=       1450247 duration   16,218
m=  10000 n=1000000 result=       1494798 duration  134,486
m= 100000 n=   1000 result=        149664 duration   18,795
m= 100000 n=  10000 result=       1449668 duration   18,451
m= 100000 n= 100000 result=      10000000 duration   27,568
m= 100000 n=1000000 result=      14490326 duration  149,033
m=1000000 n=   1000 result=        149664 duration  153,541
m=1000000 n=  10000 result=       1495165 duration  129,903
m=1000000 n= 100000 result=      14510529 duration  141,377
m=1000000 n=1000000 result=     100000000 duration  278,689
```

and these results in Java 8:

```
m=   1000 n=   1000 result=        100000 duration    4,271
m=   1000 n=  10000 result=        144379 duration   10,414
m=   1000 n= 100000 result=        149303 duration   45,413
m=   1000 n=1000000 result=        149336 duration  179,397
m=  10000 n=   1000 result=        145269 duration    7,422
m=  10000 n=  10000 result=       1000000 duration    6,464
m=  10000 n= 100000 result=       1450247 duration   54,259
m=  10000 n=1000000 result=       1494798 duration  158,869
m= 100000 n=   1000 result=        149664 duration   17,863
m= 100000 n=  10000 result=       1449668 duration   16,904
m= 100000 n= 100000 result=      10000000 duration   33,613
m= 100000 n=1000000 result=      14490326 duration  158,988
m=1000000 n=   1000 result=        149664 duration  133,977
m=1000000 n=  10000 result=       1495165 duration  139,210
m=1000000 n= 100000 result=      14510529 duration  156,483
m=1000000 n=1000000 result=     100000000 duration 1080,306
```

You can see that the results are *approximately* equal, except for the last one. Starting it again, and additionally specifying `-verbose:gc` shows the reason:

```
...
m=1000000 n= 100000 result=      14510529 duration  156,934
...
[Full GC (Ergonomics)  64237K->24095K(79360K), 0.7443466 secs]
m=1000000 n=1000000 result=     100000000 duration 1056,624
```

It performs a full garbage collection before the last pass. (Something like this would be avoided when using one of the above mentioned benchmarking frameworks!).

Now one could start some GC tuning, and there are many, many articles about that (this is not only an art, this is a *black* art). But the actual *reason* for the GC can be derived from the program: It is creating lots and lots of `Integer` objects that have to be cleaned up.

Depending in the *size* of the `Integer` objects in these lists, this may be avoided. The autoboxing from `int` to `Integer` internally relies on a cache for "small" `int` values. The default size of this cache is rather small. But when starting the above mentioned program with `-XX:AutoBoxCacheMax=300`, nearly all GC pauses will disappear, because there simply are no `Integer` values larger than 300 in this test.

---

An aside: Here is simple modification of the program to use parallel streams

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class ParallelSortingSpeedTest {

    private static List<Integer> createList(int n, int offset, int range) {
        Random random = new Random(0);
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(n);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            list.add(random.nextInt(range) + offset);
        }
        return list;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int m = 1000; m <= 1000000; m *= 10) {
            for (int n = 1000; n <= 1000000; n *= 10) {

                runTest(m, n);
            }
        }

    }

    private static void runTest(int m, int n) {
        List<Integer> list1 = createList(m, 0, 100);
        List<Integer> list2 = createList(n, 100, 100);

        long before = System.nanoTime();
        list1 = list1.parallelStream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
        list2 = list2.parallelStream().sorted(
            Collections.reverseOrder()).collect(Collectors.toList());
        int max = Math.min(list1.size(), list2.size());
        int a, b;
        long result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
            a = list1.get(i);
            b = list2.get(i);
            if (b > a)
                result += (b - a);
            else
                break;
        }
        long after = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.printf("m=%7d n=%7d result=%14d duration %8.3f\n", m, n,
                result, (after - before) / 1e6);
    }
}
```

In this case, you may even observe a slight speedup with Java 8:

```
....
m=1000000 n=  10000 result=       1495165 duration   95,386
m=1000000 n= 100000 result=      14510529 duration   95,467
m=1000000 n=1000000 result=     100000000 duration  172,782
```

Answer (score 3):

There can be several reasons but my first guess is that Java 8 comes with lots of additional features thus the initial load time is larger.

If we assume `n` is not significantly large, one can argue the processing time is negligible.

With which order of numbers (`n` and `m`) do you execute the program?

You also provide the numbers using `stdin`. I assume you use some kind of pipe? Otherwise entering the values is of course part of the processing time...

In order to benchmark this more effectively, you need to **repeat** your experiment numerous times in the same run... Only then the processing time becomes the dominating factor.

Comment: Considering that the lists have to be filled by hand, probably with small n and m

Comment: @LionC Input could also be piped from a text file.

Comment: I don't understand "With which order of numbers .." It is solution to this problem http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/439/D and there are ranges of n and m. In the last test n and m are 100000

Comment: It could, but if that was the case i would think that he would have used Files in his short code example for us. Anyways, only OP can clarify anyways :-)

Comment: @Dwq: well 100000 is not really a significant number. Sorting is *O(n log n)* (well theoretically *O(n^2)*) but given `n` is `100 000` in magnitude, one expects a few milliseconds processing time. Thus the `x00` milliseconds difference must have another reason...

Comment: but time limit on such problems are usually 1000 ms and 500+ more ms is a significant difference. What about memory ? In java 7 I have 112 KB, whereas in java 8  3664 KB

Comment: I don't know why, but I *suspect* that you did not enter the 100000 numbers manually at the console...

Comment: I wrote that it is solution to this problem http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/439/D , so I don't have to enter numbers manually